# Identify 433MHz RF interface chip with markings `119B D904 125`

Tags: identification, surface-mount

I'm trying to identify an unknown QFN chip originating from a door/window contact sensor. The sensor is manufactured by Climax but [the manual](https://manuals.plus/m/f8b1e09c03095e4989156fd23e5705c52f01d01817e05a51543422f1b542c8c9_optim.pdf) has little clues, besides model number `MDC-3`. I found it in the [FCC database](https://fccid.io/GX9MDC3R2/Test-Report/Test-Report-6637358) which says it's transmitting on 433MHz.

The chip in question is a small square package, labeled as `119B` `D904` `125`. Since the sensor uses another TI part I tried their catalog, but to no avail.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The 430G2553 is a MSP430G2553, so that's the main controller. As the MSP350G2553 has no RF frontend integrated and the antenna is connected to that chip, it's probably some RF interface.

Comment: It is most likely some sort of key fob chip, something similar to an EV1527 or maybe LoRa.

Comment: This seems to be proprietary 433Mhz frontend maybe? This issue is for a bit of context: https://github.com/merbanan/rtl_433/issues/2724